# Django QuerySet returns nothing

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of countries, they all have there own url www.example.com/al/ for example. There is a list of cities for every country but the object_list is empty

My View:

```
class CityOverview(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'shisha/pages/country_index.html'
    model = City

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        country_id = self.kwargs.get('country_id')
        return City.objects.filter(country__name=country_id)
```

My Model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        ('al', 'Albania'),
        ('ad', 'Andorra'),
        #etc. etc.
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default='nl')

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

My Urls:

```
path('<str:country_id>', views.CityOverview.as_view(), name='country'),
```

My Template:

```
{{ object_list }}
```

It returns an empty QuerySet

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Your code looks ok. If `object_list` is empty for `www.example.com/al/` that suggests there aren't any cities with country set to Albania in the database. Note that there's a mismatch between `www.example.com/al/` (with trailing slash) and  `path('<str:country_id>', ...)` (no trailing slash). What *exact* URL are you going to, and what cities do you expect there to be in the queryset?

Comment: No the object is not empty I looked like a 100 times in the db to make sure it isn't empty. and the exact url i'm going to is (www.example.com/al) so no trailling slash. @Alasdair

Comment: If this is a legacy database or you changed your models, then perhaps the database doesn’t match your models. If you won’t show the data in your database then I don’t have any more suggestions, since the code looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

May be your returning query is wrong,

```
class Country(Models.model):
     country_id=Autofield()
     country_name=CharaField()
```

in Views.py

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    country_id = self.kwargs.get('country_id')
    return City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that i need to query this in de models.py?

Comment: No. you have to add this in views.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to match `country__name` to `country_id`. Alter the last line in `get_queryset` to become `return City.objects.filter(country__id=country_id)` which will now filter the `country_id` supplied against `City`'s country id.

Comment: Already tried that it returns this error: **invalid literal for int() with base 10**

Comment: You are probably using `country_id` as a string. Try casting the value to an integer i.e `return City.objects.filter(country__id=int(country_id))`